# client.run('mytoken') crashes and i dont know why

Tags: python, discord

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in

```
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start

```
exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
```

File "", line 39

```
client.run('token')

^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]

i tried to make a welcome message say a random joke from radapi or whatever its called,and this is what happened

Comment: Most likely a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: yeah i forgor to do something